# count total number of records where imagefk is equal to ? in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a table in the db where I can count the total number of records in the table where imagefk is equal to the parameter given. Here is a possible structure of the table

```
id | reviews | bookname | imagefk
1  |  1      | xyz      | null
2  |  1      | xyz      | 53
3  |  1      | xyz      | 53
```

Using below to return the total count of reviews where imagefk is equal to the parameter given, it returns all records instead of the three rows

```
public function getAllImagesAction(String imagefk)
    {
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select('count(e.reviews)');
            $qb->from('xxxBundle:Books','e')
                    ->add('where', 'e.imagefk = imagefk'); // making the parameter dynamic and to pull from the url routing.yml file
            $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

my challenge with the above query is that the where clause does not count 2 records based on this parameter

instead it counts 3 records. Please what could be wrong. Kindly assist

Comment: You didn't show your `e.upcount` column. What is it set to for all 3 records?

Comment: Post complete definition of `xxxBundle:Books` entity

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid the complete definition is what I have defined in the structure provided

Comment: @Float I suspect `imagefk` is not a column instead its a mapping to another entity like many to one i guess that is why i asked you to show the entity code/definition

Comment: yeah. its a one to many column definition and I am posting the relation now

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have edited my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join your entity with Images entity and then you can add where clause on image id like

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('count(b.reviews)')
       ->from('xxxBundle:Books','b')
       ->join('b.imagerating','i')
       ->where('i.id = :id')
       ->setParameter('id', 53);       
$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: it worked, but I will like the id to be dynamic like to pass the imagefk parameter to the method argument

Comment: I guess you should ask a new question with all the details you have

Comment: its just to make the parameter pull from the method argument instead of hard coding it with 53

Comment: @Float From which method ? that is why i asked you. Or you can update your question with the required details as of now from one liner description it hard to determine what you want to achieve

Comment: I have gottent what I wanted to achieve thanks for accepting to help... gracias